# Data-Binding: Display a list of strings

Tags: c#, wpf, gridview, data-binding

I have got a class called Track:

```
public class Track
{
    public string Title { get; set; }      
    public List<Artist> Artists { get; set; }

}
```

This class contains a list of Artist objects:

```
public class Artist
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Now I want to bind this to a GridView in WPF:

```
 <ListView x:Name="TracksList" Margin="37,325,33,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.ColumnSpan="1" MouseDoubleClick="TrackList_MouseDoubleClick" Foreground="#FFDEDEDE" Background="#FF232323">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Title}" Width="400px" Header="Titel" />
                    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Artists}" Width="200px" Header="Artists" />     
                </GridView> 
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
```

I use the a List of Track objects to fill this GridView:

```
TracksList.ItemsSource = album.TrackCollection;
```

What I want to achieve is to display a string containg all the artist names in the Artists column (e.g. "Artist 1, Artist 2, Artist 3"). What I get is a string explaining that this field contains a list. I do understand why I get this result: I did not tell the binding how to resolve and display the list.

How can I configure the binding so that a list of the artists is displayed in the column fields.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: could  you explain more what you  means by e.g. "Artist 1, Artist 2, Artist 3" are in the some row or are in different rows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use a [Binding.Converter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.converter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) like this:

```
class ArtistsListConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(
        object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        object result = null;
        var artists = value as IEnumerable<Artist>;

        if (artists != null)
        {
            result = string.Join(", ", artists.Select(a => a.Name));
        }

        return result;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(
        object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<local:ArtistsListConverter x:Key="ArtistsListConverter"/>
...
DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Artists,
                       Converter={StaticResource ArtistsListConverter}}"
```

Answer (score 1):

That's why there are view models:

```
public class TrackViewModel
{
    public TrackViewModel(Track model)
    {
        Title = model.Title;
        Artists = string.Join(", ", model.Artists.Select(a => a.Name));
    }

    public string Title { get; private set; }
    public string Artists { get; private set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you bind the List of Artist the converter is actually getting that only. So, this is the slightly improvised version of Converter.

```
public class ArtistsToStringConverter : System.Windows.Data.IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var artists = value as IEnumerable<Artist>;

        if (artists != null)
        {
            var artistNames = from artist in artists select artist.Name;
            return string.Join(", ", artistNames);
        }
        return null;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```